# Upload gist upon travis-ci failure

Tags: unit-testing, travis-ci, gist

I have an open source project that I'd like to test using travis-ci. Sadly it is rather flaky and I'd like to know the reason. The tests write very verbose log files, so I'd like to export these, upon failure to Github Gist. There are command line tools that allow me to do that, `gist-paste` for instance, however I don't know how to run them only upon failure and without overriding the return code of the unittests, i.e., I'd still like travis-ci to notice the failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great idea. Travis CI has a step in the build lifecycle called `after_failure` which will be fired after your testing `script` step has run and failed, as outlined on the ["customizing the build" documentation page here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#The-Build-Lifecycle).

In your `.travis.yml` file, you would add an `after_failure` step with a call to your `gist-paste` command, after setting the relevant Git tokens as encrypted environment variables I assume. You can then access plenty of information about the build from the [many environment variables set by Travis during the build](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/).

Comment: Thanks for pointing the `after_failure` step out. The one downside of `gist-paste` is that you have to upload individual log files. So I switched over to https://transfer.sh/ which allows me to `tar` all files (including artifacts) and upload them. They are deleted after a timeout of a few days, but by that time I should have fixed the failure anyway :-)

Comment: Will `after_failure` fire if a `before_install` step fails?

Comment: @user1795832 I don't think so. As quoted from the ["Customizing the Build"](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#Breaking-the-Build) page "If `before_install`, `install` or `before_script` return a non-zero exit code, the build is **errored** and stops immediately."

Comment: OK thanks.  I have a similar issue but it fails during a before_install step (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46329660/how-to-get-log-files-generated-during-travis-build), and I'm not sure how to extract that file.