# Export travis log after build

Tags: ruby, build, travis-ci

I am using Travis-ci for building my programs but I needed its log for some processing. So is there a way to export Travis-ci logs after every build in the text file?

Comment: why do you need to process the logs, just wondering if there is another way...

Comment: @Kris  those logs contain output of my programs which I need to verify against test cases and send back the response in an email to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're able to get your tests to output their results to a text file log, you can then use the Travis `after_success` and/or `after_failure` build lifecycle steps ([documentation here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#The-Build-Lifecycle)) to run a command which will send you the log files or upload them somewhere.

See [my answer to a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181218/upload-gist-upon-travis-ci-failure/40777099#40777099).