# How to get log files generated during Travis build?

Tags: travis-ci, build-process

I have a Travis build that keeps failing, and I'm trying to get the `.env` file mentioned in the env-file below.  I tried putting `after_failure: "cat /Users/travis/.opam/system/build/topkg.0.9.0/topkg-19768-81a3ce.env"` in the yml, but it didn't do anything. How would I go about getting this file? This is also during a `before_install` step.

```
#=== ERROR while installing topkg.0.9.0 =======================================#
# opam-version 1.2.2
# os           darwin
# command      ocaml pkg/pkg.ml build --pkg-name topkg --dev-pkg false
# path         /Users/travis/.opam/system/build/topkg.0.9.0
# compiler     system (4.05.0)
# exit-code    2
# env-file     /Users/travis/.opam/system/build/topkg.0.9.0/topkg-20472-81a3ce.env
# stdout-file  /Users/travis/.opam/system/build/topkg.0.9.0/topkg-20472-81a3ce.out
# stderr-file  /Users/travis/.opam/system/build/topkg.0.9.0/topkg-20472-81a3ce.err
### stdout ###
# Cannot find file topfind.
### stderr ###
# Unknown directive 'require'.
```

Comment: Can we see your `.travis.yml` file?

Comment: Additionally, the full log would also be instructive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached out to Travis support on this and they told me that any errors during the `before_install` step will not generate the contents of a log into the Travis build log.